# Angular 4 not rendering non english text consistently

Tags: angular, typescript, character-encoding

In my web app, I am adding the ability to display the page in a different language.

Angular 4 seems to not  be rendering non english text consistently. Any ideas why?

[image: Screenshot of inconsistent rendering]

I have some spanish which contains an ay-knee-ay and it is rendered correctly on some parts of the page and not others.

The two locations are are in the same font and are actual duplicate `html` (I know thats bad but I'm just prototyping so I gave each component a translator button for testing).

Both of my `html` files are in `cp1252` also. I am testing in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: are you using Angular's `il8n` providers? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html#!#angular-i18n

Comment: No, I am following this tutorial -> https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-language-translation-in-angular-2-part-1